# difference between eth0:1 and eth0.1

Tags: nic

Is there any difference in eth0:1 and eth0.1. I a little confused with dot and colon notation. Have seen different approaches but appears both work in the same way, but I need some clarification on this

Answer (score 0):

This is what I know:
eth0.1 is used for tagged vlan (IEEE 802.1Q) and has to be enabled in the kernel. It adds a VLAN tag to the Ethernet protocol. The VLAN Tag includes for example priority handling of Ethernet messages.

eth0:1 is called virtual interface and has has not to be enabled in the kernel.

This is what I think:
The virtual Interface does not add a VLAN Tag to the Ethernet protocol. Therefore it is more like eth0 just with a differet IP adress.